# Python date compression

Tags: python, datetime, serialization, compression

I m making a script to store date information in the smallest size in bits

(I don't mind of the actually memory use in the program / runtime)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import datetime

MAGIC = "DAT"

def extract(data, size):
    return (((data >> size) << size) ^ data)

def compress_date(year, month, day, hour, minute):
    assert year <= 31
    assert month <= 12
    assert day <= 31
    assert hour <= 24
    assert minute <= 60

    data = 0
    data = (data << 5) + year
    data = (data << 4) + month
    data = (data << 5) + day
    data = (data << 5) + hour
    data = (data << 6) + minute
    return (data)

def decompress_date(data):
    minute = extract(data, 6)
    data >>= 6

    hour = extract(data, 5)
    data >>= 5

    day = extract(data, 5)
    data >>= 5

    month = extract(data, 4)
    data >>= 4

    year = extract(data, 5)
    data >>= 5
    return (year, month, day, hour, minute)

date = serialgen.compress_date(10, 11, 30, 24, 60)
print date
print hex(date)
print decompress_date(date)
```

output:

```
11269692
0xabf63c
(10, 11, 30, 24, 60)
```

Can I do something to clear up the ugly parts:

```
data = 0
data = (data << 5) + year
data = (data << 4) + month
data = (data << 5) + day
data = (data << 5) + hour
data = (data << 6) + minute

minute = extract(data, 6)
data >>= 6

hour = extract(data, 5)
data >>= 5

day = extract(data, 5)
data >>= 5

month = extract(data, 4)
data >>= 4

year = extract(data, 5)
data >>= 5
```

Do you have any suggestions to improve this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Weird limits

I have absolutely no idea of what date is "the 12th of June at 24 hour 60 minutes", yet you consider it a valid date as regard to your bounds. You should assert hours and minutes to be respectively 23 and 59 at max.

Using a two-digit long value for the date seems rather useless too. What century does it encode exactly? And assuming it is for years in the 2000 era, why limit to 2031?

#### Unused stuff

Both your imports and constant are unused, you should remove them.

#### Bitfield manipulation

Extracting informations out of a bitfield is generally done using a mask. You need to create the mask corresponding to `size` bits set using `mask = (1 << (size + 1)) - 1` and then you can use `data & mask` to get the desired value. The advantage being that you can easily add an `offset` to grab the exact portion you’re interested in:

```
def extract(data, size, offset):
    mask = (1 << (size + 1)) - 1
    return (data & (mask << offset)) >> offset

def decompress_date(data):
    minute = extract(data, 6, 0)  # minutes are at the end, no offset
    hour = extract(data, 5, 6)  # hours are after minutes (6)
    day = extract(data, 5, 11)  # days are after hours (5) and minutes (6)
    month = extract(data, 4, 16)  # you get it
    year = extract(data, 5, 20)
    return (year, month, day, hour, minute)
```

#### Value creation

You can simplify the compressed data creation by dropping useless initialization:

```
def compress(...):
    data = year
    data = (data << 4) + month
    ...
```

Knowing the offsets, you can also use them to create the compressed data all at once. To simplify reading and understanding, you can also define a bunch of constants:

```
MINUTES_SIZE = 6
HOURS_SIZE = 5
DAYS_SIZE = 5
MONTHS_SIZE = 4
YEARS_SIZE = 5

MINUTES_OFFSET = 0
HOURS_OFFSET = MINUTES_OFFSET + MINUTES_SIZE
DAYS_OFFSET = HOURS_OFFSET + HOURS_SIZE
MONTHS_OFFSET = DAYS_OFFSET + DAYS_SIZE
YEARS_OFFSET = MONTHS_OFFSET + MONTHS_SIZE

def decompress_date(data):
    minute = extract(data, MINUTES_SIZE, MINUTES_OFFSET)
    hour = extract(data, HOURS_SIZE, HOURS_OFFSET)
    day = extract(data, DAYS_SIZE, DAYS_OFFSET)
    month = extract(data, MONTHS_SIZE, MONTHS_OFFSET)
    year = extract(data, YEARS_SIZE, YEARS_OFFSET)
    return (year, month, day, hour, minute)

def compress_date(year, month, day, hour, minute):
    assert year <= 31
    assert 0 < month <= 12
    assert 0 < day <= 31
    assert 0 <= hour < 24
    assert 0 <= minute < 60

    return (
        (year << YEARS_OFFSET) +
        (month << MONTHS_OFFSET) +
        (day << DAYS_OFFSET) +
        (hour << HOURS_OFFSET) +
        (minute << MINUTES_OFFSET)
    )
```

#### Timestamps

The "classic" condensed representation of a point in time is given by a timestamp: the elapsed time in seconds since January 1st 1970. Since you’re only interested in minutes, you can create a simple wrapper around Python's `datetime.timestamp()`:

```
import datetime


def compress(date):
    return int(date.timestamp() // 60)


def compressed_date(year, month, day, hour, minute):
    return compress_date(datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute)


def uncompress(truncated_timestamp):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(truncated_timestamp * 60)
```

And support a wider variety of dates.